# Trigger function to check data exists in the table or not

Tags: database, postgresql, exception, triggers, plpgsql

```
CREATE TRIGGER id_check BEFORE DELETE ON CUSTOMER
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE check_id();


CREATE FUNCTION check_id() RETURNS trigger AS 
$$ BEGIN
    IF (SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE Customer.CustomerID = $1) IS NULL THEN
        rollback transaction;
        print "error "
END$$ 
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I would like to create an SQL trigger function to check data exist in the table or not before a delete. I have to insert a customer ID to delete its detail. If the data doesn't exist, stop the delete function and return an error. I got no idea what to do now.

Comment: can you please select just the database tag that applies. not all the ones you could find. also. why bother?

Comment: so if i understand correctly. when you want to delete a row, you first want the trigger to check and see if there is an entry to delete, and if there is no entry to delete, do nothing, otherwise, delete it?

Comment: Similar,but no entry will show an error instead of doing nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your approach is that the trigger is never fired if no row is found. The syntax hints: `FOR EACH ROW`. A trigger `FOR EACH STATEMENT` on the other hand cannot see affected rows nor the triggering statement. Catch 22.

You can encapsulate `DELETE` itself in a function or in a `DO` statement:

There you can `RAISE` an exception, which rolls back the current transaction unless caught in an exception handler:

```
CREATE FUNCTION delete_from_customer(int)
  RETURNS void AS 
$func$
BEGIN
   DELETE FROM customer WHERE customerid = $1;
   IF NOT FOUND THEN
      RAISE EXCEPTION 'DELETE failed: id % not found in table "customer"', $1;
   END;
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Call:

```
SELECT delete_from_customer(1);
```

[**SQL Fiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/36f3f/4)

Using the special plpgsql variable `FOUND` as cheap way to do this.
[More about raising errors in the manual.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-errors-and-messages.html)

#### Or you want this?

Your question is not very clear. You might want something different altogether:

> I have to insert a customer ID to delete its detail.

To verify that a row exists as condition for a `DELETE`:

```
DELETE FROM customer_detail cd
WHERE  customerid = 123
AND    EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM customer WHERE customerid = cd.customerid);
```